# How to see what types of .NET Exceptions are happening on a live system?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, webforms, windows-server-2008

Looking at the Perfmon on a live system that's running a .NET WebForms site, it shows that the worker process (w3wp) is averaging about 150 thrown exceptions per second.

Is there a way to see what types of exceptions these are?

Comment: Profilers can show live data when attached. You can also capture hang dumps and analyzed afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the EventLog for errors. I am sure you have done that already, but just in case.
2. You mentioned this is a live site, but if you have the ability to, using a non intrusive exception catcher such as [Elmah](https://elmah.github.io/) may provide some additional insights. If you do go this route, be sure to address the ["AllowRemoteAccess"](https://blog.elmah.io/elmah-security-and-allowremoteaccess-explained/) issue.